# How to move windows between dual monitors by using arrow buttons instead of dragging

Tags: multiple-monitors

I had dual monitors at a previous job that had the ability to move windows from one screen to the other by the click of an arrow button at the top of the window. I just got dual monitors at my new job and my windows do not have the arrow buttons, I have to drag the windows if I want to move them. Is there a way to get the arrow buttons added to the windows of my computer so that i have the one-click capability to move them from screen to screen?

Comment: The "arrows" you mention aren't default, it's some software your IT installed. So, ask your IT personnel.

Comment: Thank you for this information - I was googling this and could not find an accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>arrow key</kbd>  moves the selected window from screen to screen in a multi-monitor configuration in Windows versions 7 and later.

This capability is built-in to Windows and does not require additional software.

The arrow buttons you mention are likely part of a piece of video controller software that comes with certain types of video cards, usually "workstation" class cards such as Matrox.